# How to protect my guava tree from insects?

Tags: fruit-trees, pests, pest-damage

I have a guava tree that is 2-3 years old, but every summer when the fruit starts to ripe, the ripe fruit gets holes near the branch and when cut it I see small larvas crawling all inside. I did use anti insect sprays on the plant when it has flowered each year but no result. Can I get any help about it?

Comment: are you saying the larvae are inside the fruits, or in the adjacent branches? And where are you in the world?

Comment: These(larvas) are inside the fruits. And I'm in Pakistan, Asia

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is likely due to Guava fruit fly - it affects some other fruit crops too, and this pest is native to your area. The fly places its eggs near the fruits, which hatch out into larvae and make their way into the fruits, which then ruin the fruits by eating through the inside. Because this is a serious problem endemic in your area, I'm not sure there's much you can do; I was hoping there might be the equivalent of a pheremone trap for the fly, but apparently there's nothing like that, only regular treatment with pesticides. There are videos on Youtube on this subject, one in this link here  https://youtu.be/Ma3ZSlikarQ  but I'm not sure it's in your language. I don't know whether its useful or not because I can't understand it!